# Image file input with Formtastic and ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, formtastic, activeadmin

I started using formstatic but I need to make a file field with an image preview. I mean, when I edit an object, I want to see the image already linked.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The answer is to use the hint attribute :

```
ActiveAdmin.register Event do
  form :html => { :enctype => "multipart/form-data" } do |f|
    f.input :map, :as => :file, :hint => f.template.image_tag(f.object.map.url(:thumb))
  end
end
```

Bye

Comment: I'd probably add that when Event doesn't have a map, it'll fail with calling the url method on map.

This will prevent error:

`f.input :map, :as => :file, :hint => f.object.map.nil? ? f.template.content_tag(:span, "no map yet") : f.template.image_tag(f.object.map.url(:thumb))`

Comment: Thank a lot for this information but i don't have error when the Event doesn't have a map, but you are right, it's better to use that !

Comment: To work for me I had to use f.object.new_record?:
f.input :map, :as => :file, :hint => ( f.object.new_record? || f.object.map.nil? ) ? f.template.content_tag(:span, "no photo yet") : f.template.image_tag(f.object.map.url(:thumb))

Comment: I think this is a worthwhile feature to add to formtastic - if it's clever enough to know that your column represents a file (which it can: :as => :file is unneeded), it should be clever enough to provide you a preview. A hypothetical signature might be:
f.input :map, :preview => :thumb

Comment: why does one need to use f.template.image_tag instead of jsut image_tag?

Comment: This method could do with a delete file option

Comment: in the current version of AA `form(html: { multipart: true })` is enough to set the `enctype` attribute.

Comment: In Rails 4.2 / ActiveAdmin master this causes object reference to be written out as well.. See answer to remove this at http://stackoverflow.com/a/27711025/1369763

Answer (score 3):

Use [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) with formtastic

Formtasitc's [github page](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic) mentions that it supports paperclip:

> :file – a file field. Default for file-attachment attributes matching: **paperclip** or attachment_fu.

Here are some useful screencasts that will get you going:

[Paperclip](http://railscasts.com/episodes/134-paperclip)

[Cropping images](http://railscasts.com/episodes/182-cropping-images)

**EDIT:**

To display an image in a column of a grid in ActiveAdmin you need to make a custom column (This is untested and could be flawed, I'm extrapolating this from the [documentation](http://activeadmin.info/documentation.html)):

```
index do
    column "Title" do |post| 
        link_to image_tag("path to file", :alt => "post image"), admin_post_path(post)
    end
end
```

Comment: Yes, i see that but my need is for my backend. I use ActiveAdmin, so i don't write the form myself. Did you use Paperclip in backend?

Comment: I made an edit to my answer. According to the documentation you can customize grids see the [Customizing the Index Page](http://activeadmin.info/documentation.html) section.

Comment: Could you update your question with the form code? I should be able to help you add the image to it once I see it.

Answer (score 1):

Two Gems and one plugin can help your case:

Make sure you look at:

Gems:

**Paperclip**: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip

**RailsCast on PaperClip**: http://railscasts.com/episodes/134-paperclip

**CarrierWave**: https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave

**RailsCast on CarrierWave**: http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads

**Jquery File Upload**: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

**Jquery File Upload RailsCast**: http://railscasts.com/episodes/381-jquery-file-upload *(Need a Pro Account for RailsCast)*

Answer (score 1):

As @ianpetzer said, in Rails 4.2 / ActiveAdmin master the current answer causes an object reference to be written out as well. The correct answer for 2016 should be similar to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27711025/1369763):

```
form :html => { :multipart => true } do |f|
    f.inputs do
        #...
        f.input :image, required: false, hint: image_tag(object.image.url(:medium)).html_safe
        #...
    end
end
```