# Formtastic hint issue (unwanted object ID output) in ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip, activeadmin, formtastic

When I use formtastic DSL for ActiveAdmin edit form I get the following output:

> #< #< Class:0x00000006bd1f68>:0x00000006bd1018> <li
>   class="file input optional"
>   id="post_image_input"><label class="label"
>   for="post_image">Image</label><input
>   id="post_image" name="post[image]"
>   type="file" />

Why does this starts from something like result of obj.inspect and how to remove this part?

The code, causing this bug is here:

```
form :html => { :multipart => true } do |f|
    f.inputs do
        #...
        f.input :image, required: false, hint: f.template.image_tag(f.object.image.url(:medium)).html_safe
        #...
    end
    f.actions
end
```

Comment: Can you post more of your resource file? Is this an ActiveAdmin form block or a partial elsewhere?

Answer (score 8):

This should work:

```
form :html => { :multipart => true } do |f|
    f.inputs do
        #...
        f.input :image, required: false, hint: image_tag(object.image.url(:medium)).html_safe
        #...
    end
    f.actions
end
```

Comment: This looks exactly like the code in the question, could you explain what you changed?

Comment: Alright so the difference is, drop the f. and template stuff

Answer (score 1):

Try it.

```rb
    form html: { multipart: true } do |f|
        f.inputs do
            #...
            f.input :image, required: false, hint: image_tag(f.object.image.url(:medium))
            #...
        end
        f.actions
    end
```